# Pathname.writable? vs Pathname.writable_real? from Ruby on Mac OS X

Tags: ruby, macos, permissions

I am encountering permission problems in [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) and this has led me to this apparently strange observation with Ruby's `Pathname.writable?` and `Pathname.writable_real?`.

#### Machine One

On this machine I have no permission problem. Dir `/usr/local` is writable by members of the `admin` group:

```
$ ls -ld /usr/local/
drwxrwxr-x  18 root  admin  612 25 Jun 09:24 /usr/local/
```

I am in the `admin` group:

```
$ whoami
martin
$ dscl . -read /Groups/admin GroupMembership
GroupMembership: root martin
```

And Ruby reports that as well no matter if I use `writable?` or `writable_real?`:

```
$ irb
>> require "Pathname"
=> true
>> Pathname('/usr/local').writable?
=> true
>> Pathname('/usr/local').writable_real?
=> true
```

#### Machine Two

On this machine, however, I have the problem that even though `/usr/local` is writable by members of the `admin` group:

```
$ ls -ld /usr/local/
drwxrwxr-x  18 root  admin  612 24 Jun 23:12 /usr/local/
```

and I am in the `admin` group:

```
$ whoami
mgd
$ dscl . -read /Groups/admin GroupMembership
GroupMembership: root mgd sgd
```

Ruby's `Pathname.writable?` reports that `/usr/local` is *not* writable:

```
$ irb
>> require "Pathname"
=> true
>> Pathname('/usr/local').writable?
=> false
>> Pathname('/usr/local').writable_real?
=> true
```

### Why?

Can anybody explain the difference?

According to the [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/FileTest.html) the difference between the two functions are:

- `writable?`: Is the path writable by the *effective* user id of the calling process?
- `writable_real?`: Is the path writable by the *real* user id of the calling process?

I still don't understand why `Pathname.writable?` behaves differently under (apparently) equal conditions.

Comment: Probably relevant: [How do I disable System Integrity Protection (SIP) AKA "rootless" on macOs \[OS X\]](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-macos-os-x/208481#208481). See what `ls -lO /usr/local` says, and which version of OSX you're running on each.